# Result Block and Anonymous User

Tags: anonymous-authentication, sharepoint-search

I have a result block to show set of documents above the core results and this is working fine for authenticated users.

I'm facing an issue when I tried searching as an anonymous user the result is placed at the bottom or core results. On debugging the result table[0] contains data for result block and result table[1] contains data for relevant results in case of authenticated users, but, for anonymous the it is the other way.

Could someone suggest how the search result can be made consistent for both anonymous and authenticated users?